# Angular material select dropdown with fixed last element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm currently working with Angular Material [select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview).

Unfortunately I haven't found an implementation that allows me to fix an element on the bottom of the list as follows example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vyLk778k/

Also, I can't use bootstrap so basically the approach must be with angular material.
So the list items are scrollable except the last one which always should be visible and fixed at the end of the list. Here's what I got so far:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{ 'Please select one' }}</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="userSelection">
              <span *ngFor="let item of user.usersAvailable">
                <mat-option [value]="item.userName"
                  style="min-height: 67px; padding: 0px 15px; line-height: 1em;">

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <div class="p-0">
                        {{item.userName}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <div class="p-0">
                        {{item.userCountry}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </mat-option>
              </span>
              <!-- This is the element I need to be fixed -->
              <mat-option>
                {{ 'Create new user' }}
              </mat-option>
              <!-- End element I need to be fixed -->
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error>
              <ag-show-errors [control]="usersForm.controls.userSelection">
              </ag-show-errors>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

I'm expecting to get the last element of the select dropdown fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add scss style like this one :

```
/* Add this to your component's CSS/SCSS file */
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel .mat-option:last-child {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

then update your HTML to be :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>{{ 'Please select one' }}</mat-label>
<mat-select formControlName="userSelection">
    <span *ngFor="let item of user.usersAvailable">
    <mat-option [value]="item.userName"
                style="min-height: 67px; padding: 0px 15px; line-height: 1em;">
        <!-- Your existing option content here -->
    </mat-option>
    </span>
    <!-- This is the element I need to be fixed -->
    <mat-option>
    {{ 'Create new user' }}
    </mat-option>
    <!-- End element I need to be fixed -->
</mat-select>
<mat-error>
    <ag-show-errors [control]="usersForm.controls.userSelection">
    </ag-show-errors>
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: That was easier than I thought lol
Thanks mate! Works like a charm :)

Comment: There you go.
Had to google how to do it 

Comment: why not create a class "last" and applied to the last element instead of use `::ng-deep .mat-select-panel .mat-option:last-child`? BTW add the `:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5;}`